# Cannot seem to format the table effectively with css as some of the selectors are being ignored

Tags: css, outlook, office365, html-email, power-automate

I have a Power Automate flow that uses the Monday.com and Microsoft Outlook to generate a table on new records in monday.com

I have a simple flow that triggers off a new record and sends an email to the team with the details of that record.

Problem: I cannot seem to format the table effectively with css as some of the selectors are being ignored. for example I have a .header that I am using that is not responding to width. the th/td and other selectors are responding, just not the .header.
** in the sample below I have commented out the width attribute but have tried about 25 variations. commenting it out led me to believe it was not being read as there was no change on the width. **
Sample:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .record-details { font-family: Arial; color: #333; }

        .table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 250px;            
            table-layout: auto;  
        }
        .header {             
            /*width: 250px; Match table width */
            font-weight: bold; 
            color: white;             
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #000080; 
            text-align: center; 
           
        }
        th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 8px;            
        }              
        .label-cell {
            background-color: lightgrey;
            color: black;
            font-weight: bold;
            width: 20%;
        }
        .data-cell {            
            background-color: white; 
            word-wrap: break-word;
            word-break: break-all;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="record-details">
        <div class="header">Pipeline Alert</div>
        <table>
              <!-- Add more headers as needed -->              

            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="label-cell">Proposal Name:</td>  <!-- here you add the title of the row -->
                <td class="data-cell">@{body('Get_an_item_by_ID')?['itemName']}</td> <!-- here you add the element you want from monday.com -->
   <tr>
                <td class="label-cell">Status:</td>  <!-- here you add the title of the row -->
                <td class="data-cell">@{body('Get_an_item_by_ID')?['status8&&&color&&&label']}</td> <!-- here you add the element you want from monday.com --><tr>
                <td class="label-cell">Stretto BD Member(s):</td>  <!-- here you add the title of the row -->
                <td class="data-cell">@{body('Get_an_item_by_ID')?['bd_lead_s_&&&dropdown&&&labels']}</td> <!-- here you add the element you want from monday.com --><tr>
                <td class="label-cell">Referral Firm(s) - Contact(s):</td>  <!-- here you add the title of the row -->
                <td class="data-cell">@{body('Get_an_item_by_ID')?['short_text&&&text&&&text']} - @{body('Get_an_item_by_ID')?['short_text21&&&text&&&text']}</td> <!-- here you add the element you want from monday.com --><tr>
                <td class="label-cell">Debtor Counsel:</td>  <!-- here you add the title of the row -->
                <td class="data-cell">@{body('Get_an_item_by_ID')?['short_text1&&&text&&&text']} - @{body('Get_an_item_by_ID')?['short_text6&&&text&&&text']}</td> <!-- here you add the element you want from monday.com --><tr>
                <td class="label-cell">Filing Date:</td>  <!-- here you add the title of the row -->
                <td class="data-cell">@{body('Get_an_item_by_ID')?['short_text11&&&text&&&text']}</td> <!-- here you add the element you want from monday.com --><tr>
                <td class="label-cell">Jurisdiction:</td>  <!-- here you add the title of the row -->
                <td class="data-cell">@{body('Get_an_item_by_ID')?['multi_select09&&&dropdown&&&labels']}</td> <!-- here you add the element you want from monday.com --><tr>
                <td class="label-cell">Industry:</td>  <!-- here you add the title of the row -->
                <td class="data-cell">@{body('Get_an_item_by_ID')?['short_text9&&&text&&&text']}</td> <!-- here you add the element you want from monday.com --><tr>
                <td class="label-cell"># Debtors: </td>  <!-- here you add the title of the row -->
                <td class="data-cell">@{body('Get_an_item_by_ID')?['__debtors&&&text&&&text']}</td> <!-- here you add the element you want from monday.com --><tr><td class="label-cell"># Noticing Parties:</td>  <!-- here you add the title of the row -->
                <td class="data-cell">@{body('Get_an_item_by_ID')?['__noticing_parties&&&text&&&text']}</td> <!-- here you add the element you want from monday.com --><tr>
                <td class="label-cell">Public?:</td>  <!-- here you add the title of the row -->
                <td class="data-cell">@{body('Get_an_item_by_ID')?['true___false&&&boolean&&&state']}</td> <!-- here you add the element you want from monday.com --><tr>
                <td class="label-cell">Other Notes:</td>  <!-- here you add the title of the row -->
                <td class="data-cell">@{body('Get_an_item_by_ID')?['long_text1&&&long-text&&&text']}</td> <!-- here you add the element you want from monday.com -->
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Outcome in Outlook:
[image]

Desired Outcome: I am trying to just make the table header match the table with all other formatting in tact. I would like it to be dynamic in the sense of adjusting as the window adjusts but will take a uniform table at this point.

The client wants the horizontal table with the headers on the left so that needs to remain and my lack of experience led me to this solution (that should answer the "why did you do it that way question, :)

We are on O365 outlook v2311

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. I was able to create a `<th>` row, use `colspan`, and style that as `<th>` rather than the `class=header`.